# FileSystemWatcher Changed event reentrancy?

Tags: c#, .net

This is a question about the `FileSystemWatcher` `Changed` event. I'm curious to know what happens if the watcher detects a second file change while the event handler code is still executing in response to a previous file change. Does it:

1. Immediately raise the event again, resulting in two threads executing the event handler code
2. Wait for the first event handler to finish executing before raising the event a second time
3. Not raise the event at all if the handler is executing

Edit: I've just created a quick console app to test this, and I was surprised to find that the FSW enqueues the handler calls, which I wasn't expecting. It's even able to handle multiple changes that occur while the first handler is executing, so I'm guessing it must implement some form of queue?

(Obviously it also calls the handler twice for each change, which is a known issue with the FSW).

Comment: _"I'm guessing it must implement some form of queue?"_ - Yes it does. And it's a _bounded_ one. Which is the cause of overflows being able to happen. Which in turn is the reason for the recommendation that EventHandlers shall do as little as possible and shall execute as fast as possible.

Comment: ^^ That's what this refers to: _"The Windows operating system notifies your component of file changes in a buffer created by the FileSystemWatcher. If there are many changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow. This causes the component to lose track of changes in the directory, and it will only provide blanket notification."_ - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/runtime-libraries/system-io-filesystemwatcher

Comment: It is a thin wrapper for the [ReadDirectoryChangesW() winapi function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw).  Note the lpBuffer argument, that's the "queue" you're talking about.  Just an array.  The FileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize property sets the size of that array.  The physical array lives in precious kernel memory pool memory, so is limited to 64KB.   Don't skimp on the Error event to detect buffer overflow.  At completion, it steps through the buffer to fire events, so no overlap.